# Tomcat on Windows 10: give permissions to write in specific folder

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, file-storage

I have Tomcat on Windows 10 with deployed app on it. It runs well except of when application tries to save file in filestore it throws an error. 
Filestore is a folder on the disc path to which is defined in context.xml like this:

```
<Resource name="ххххх/FileStore"
type="org.ххххххх.filestore.FileStoreService"
factory="org.ххххххх.filestore.impl.LocalFileStoreFactory"
baseDir="/E:/files"
domain="ххххх"/>
```

Tomcat sees this path correctly and directory E:/files/xxxxx really exists. For testing purpose I have ran this app with Tomcat on Ubuntu and this process passed just fine. Also I emulated "Windows" error on Ubuntu by restricting the permission for Tomcat to write in filestore folder.
What i tried so far:

1. Gave all permission to write in the folder to everyone and to services (as I ran it like user or like a service) and to all other groups just in case.
2. Disable UAC, firewall, other "protective" soft, ran like administrator from GUI, command line, powershell.
3. Shared this folder in the network with permissions to write for everyone (password off). Tested it from another PC. Modified context.xml accordingly.

Is there another options that can help to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was not in permissions. I forgot that Windows file system not allows to do several action with the file simultaneously, like in my case.